# Match PotsgreSQL timestamptz by exact value

Tags: javascript, postgresql, timestamp, equality, supabase

I am using PostgreSQL 13.3 via Supabase.io.  I have a table with a field called modified_at which has a type of timestamptz:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS knowledge_views (
  id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
  modified_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()) NOT NULL
);
```

I have an entry in it where the modified_at is: `2021-09-27T20:55:25.625Z` (edit: it's not, Supabase currently hides the microseconds).  None of the following statements work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM knowledge_views WHERE modified_at = timestamptz '2021-09-27T20:55:25.625Z';

SELECT * FROM knowledge_views WHERE modified_at = '2021-09-27T20:55:25.625Z'::timestamptz;

SELECT * FROM knowledge_views WHERE modified_at = to_timestamp(1632776125.625);

SELECT * FROM knowledge_views WHERE modified_at >= to_timestamp(1632776125.625) AND modified_at <= to_timestamp(1632776125.625);
```

However if take the last query and increment the milliseconds of the `<=` by one to `1632776125.626` then it correctly finds the row:

```sql
SELECT * FROM knowledge_views WHERE modified_at >= to_timestamp(1632776125.625) AND modified_at <= to_timestamp(1632776125.626);
```

Is there a way to select a row by an exact timestamptz value including milliseconds?

If that is not possible, is the (hacky) approach of adding 1 to the maximum millisecond value robust?  Or should I also decrement one from the minimum value e.g.: `>= to_timestamp(1632776125.624) AND modified_at <= to_timestamp(1632776125.626)`?

** edit **

Using the following it shows the field is actually stored with microsecond precision:

```sql
SELECT modified_at as original, cast(extract(epoch from modified_at) * 1000000 as bigint) FROM knowledge_views;
```

| original | int8 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-27T20:55:25.**625**Z | 1632776125**625***535* |

I realised it was working before as the client left the timestamp value string unchanged, i.e.:

```
supabase.from("knowledge_views").select("*").eq("modified_at", "2021-09-27T20:55:25.625535")
```

This broke when I used: `new Date("2021-09-27T20:55:25.625535")` which dropped the microseconds.

Comment: What is your timezone set to?  Are you running community PostgreSQL or some fork?  How did you install it?  What non-default settings do you have?  What OS and version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an entry in it where the modified_at is: `2021-09-27T20:55:25.625Z`.

How do you know that's the exact value? I am asking because Postgres timestamps have **microsecond resolution** (6 fractional digits). Trailing zeroes are not displayed by default, but the chance that `now()` (in your odd column `DEFAULT`) produced a timestamp rounded to milliseconds exactly are 1 in 1000. Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

My guess is that your client reports **timestamps rounded to milliseconds** (maybe due to an unfortunate setting?). Run `SELECT * FROM knowledge_views;` in a sane client like the [default PostgreSQL interactive terminal `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to get the actual value. Then you'll find that the `=` operator works as expected for `timestamptz`.

Comment: This may clarify the case in a client with 'unfortunate setting'. `select to_char(modified_at, '.FF3') mils, to_char(modified_at, '.US') micros, modified_at from knowledge_views;`. It clearly confirms the above - a truncation issue.

Comment: `sane client` is the order of the day here!  Thank you.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm that's very useful.  Thank you.  It showed: `| .625 | .625535 | 2021-09-27T20:55:25.625Z |`

Comment: I'm going to use `now()::timestamp(3)` on insert, update so that it's trivial to use the datetimes strings with javascript Date which lacks microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would ditch the `DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now())`. `timestamptz` values are stored in `UTC` already, all you are doing is transposing the value in a way you don't want:

```
 show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific

create table tstz_test(id integer, tstz_fld timestamptz);

insert into tstz_test values (1, now()), (2, timezone('UTC', now()));

select * from tstz_test ;
 id |           tstz_fld            
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2021-09-27 16:56:35.964202-07
  2 | 2021-09-27 23:56:35.964202-07

select tstz_fld AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' from tstz_test ;
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2021-09-27 23:56:35.964202
 2021-09-28 06:56:35.964202

 select * from tstz_test where tstz_fld = '2021-09-27 23:56:35.964202Z'::timestamptz;
 id |           tstz_fld            
----+-------------------------------
  1 | 2021-09-27 16:56:35.964202-07
```

So milliseconds is not the issue.